# Why does my dynamic physics body go through my static physics body?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a dynamic physics body called "bo" and one called "leftBumper".  When they collide, I want the bumper to stay in place and I want Bo to bounce off the bumper.

Instead, when they collide, Bo keeps moving and the bumper goes flying off the screen.  It  seems they are both dynamic.  Here is my code:

BO:

```
    bo.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    bo.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = boCategory // 3
    bo.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = chainsawCategory // 4
    bo.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = noneCategory & bumperCategory
    addChild(bo)
```

BUMPER:

```
 leftBumper.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    leftBumper.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: leftBumper.size)
    leftBumper.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bumperCategory
    leftBumper.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = boCategory

    leftBumper.zPosition = 10

    addChild(leftBumper)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ain't gonna work:

```
leftBumper.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
leftBumper.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: leftBumper.size)
```

You set the flag at a time where the physicsBody is nil (or a previous body) and then you create a new instance of the body which will default to having the dynamic flag set to true. First, create the body, then change its properties.

Second, before setting the bitmasks, try to make it work without them. You should check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/categoryBitMask) how they work. The bitmasks are frequently misunderstood.

In this case both bo and bumper have their own categories but they won't generate contact events cause bo's contact bitmask is set to the chainsaw category which the bumper does not use at all. If you want them to contact *and* collide, the bo needs to have the bumper category in its contact and collision bitmasks, while the bumper needs to have the bo category in its contact and collision bitmasks.

Comment: Actually, I tried your suggestion and removed the bitMasks from the bumper and it worked!